# How to capture all mockito spied class method invocations without counting inner delegations

Tags: java, mockito, spy, method-invocation

Assuming that with a class like:

```
public class A {
    public void smth {
    }
    public void smth2 {
        smth();
    }
}
```

We spy it with mockito and make a simple call :

```
A spiedA = spy(new A());
spiedA.smth2();
```

After that when we want to retrieve call count:

```
Mockito.mockingDetails(spiedA).getInvocations().size()
```

And it returns two calls as expected. But i want to only register outside calls without inner delegations. Is there possibility to achieve the result i demand? If only Mockito.Invocation could provide with call stack i would filter it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved. Wrapped in java.lang.reflect.Proxy with custom invocation handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Location location` field in `Invocation` class. In has actually stack trace inside (which is actually private field, so you should make it available through reflection). And after that you can grab required information, something like that:

```
((LocationImpl)((LinkedList<Invocation>) invocations).get(1).getLocation()).stackTraceHolder.stackTrace
```

But I would really **not recommend to do that**, because you would not want to maintain that test in the future.
You can extract `smth()` into different class and spy on it if you really need.

Comment: Yea i know about that trick but it's hacky/ugly and not good approach after all. Extraction is also not an option unfortunately.